# Graph theory exercise reduced to finding integer solutions for $x^2 +y^2 = 2020$.

Tags: graph-theory

I have stumbled upon the following simple Graph Theory problem:

> In a rooted tree we have 2021 nodes. Each level has a perfect square number of nodes. All leaves are on the same level. What is the minimum number of levels to distribute all 2021 nodes of the tree?

I noticed the problem comes down to finding the integer solutions of the $x^2 +y^2 = 2020$ equation. Of course that trying every integer from 1 to 45 would result in a solution, but I was wondering if there is any theorem according to which it is guaranteed for such pair $(x,y)$ to exist.

Comment: Use the facts that $101=10^2+1^2, 5=2^2+1^2, 4=2^2+0^2$ and $2020=101\cdot 5\cdot 4$ with ["Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$. Or, refer to [Sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem).

Comment: I would say that the problem is to find the smallest $k$ such that $2020$ is the sum of $k$ squares, with the graph theory stuff only being an obfuscation. And finding *a* solution (you only need one) to $x^2 + y^2 = 2020$ is how you show the answer is $k = 2$.